# Why don't all CSS buttons make use of vertical padding instead of fixed height?

Tags: html, css

In CSS, I can effectively create the same buttons in 2 ways. For example:

```css
.btn-1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
.btn-2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-1">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn-2">Button 2</button>
```

The first button is making use of vertical padding, while the second button is making use of height and line-height.

Now, I looked at the design for buttons on many popular websites, and a lot of them seem to be using the second approach, ie, setting the height and line height. My question is this: why are they doing this? I am planning on making a site where the buttons use vertical padding and I am wondering if there are issues that I am not being able to predict. What are the cons of using buttons with vertical padding instead of height?

Comment: use different font-size/font-family and things will be different